# Why do I get an error when using Backbone and requirejs in todo example?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I dont understand why I receive this error: TypeError: State.setActive is not a function, when using Backbone and Requirejs.

I stripped out some of the code to simplify.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

**Model**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',

], function($, Backbone, _ ) {
    'use strict';

    var State = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            activeTask: ''
        },

        setActive: function(model){
            State.set({activeTask : State.get('activeTask') === model.id ? '' : model.id});
        }

    });

    _.extend(State, Backbone.Events);

    return State;
});
```

**View**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/state-model',

],  function ( $, _, Backbone, State) {
        'use strict';

        var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

            tagName:  'li',

            template: _.template($('#todo-template').html()),


            initialize: function () {
                this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

            },

            events: {

                "dblclick .view" : "clickActive",

            },

            render: function(){
                 this.$el.toggleClass('done', this.model.get('done'));
                 this.$el.toggleClass('active', this.model.get('active'));
                 this.toggleVisible();           
                 this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                 return this;
            },


            clickActive: function() {

                State.setActive(this.model);
                this.model.toggleActive();

            }

    });

    return TodoView;

});
```

Comment: You aren't *instantiating* your state model anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not instantiating your state model anywhere. When you `return State` from your State module that only returns the *class*.

If State is meant to be a *singleton* then you can instantiate it within it's own module and return that. Otherwise your best option is probably to pass in the module when you create instantiate your todo views.

For example

```
var state = new State();
var todo = new TodoView ({state: state, model: myModel});
```

And in your TodoView View

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:  'li',

    template: _.template($('#todo-template').html()),


    initialize: function (options) {
        this.state = options.state;
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

State is a constructor, you have to instantiate it. Try this in model (assuming you want it to be a singleton):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'backbone',
    'underscore',

], function($, Backbone, _ ) {
    'use strict';

    var State = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            activeTask: ''
        },

        setActive: function(model){
           State.set({activeTask : State.get('activeTask') === model.id ? '' : model.id});
        }

    });

    _.extend(State, Backbone.Events);

    return State(); // <- change here
});
```